# How to identify the Username and Password field to login into USPS.com using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to login in USPS.com, my username and password are correct and I am using following code.

```
user1="myusername"
password1="password"
url="https://reg.usps.com/login?app=MyUSPS"
browser.get(url)

username = browser.find_element_by_name('username')
username.send_keys(user1)
sleep(5)
password = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys(passwd1)
sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_id('btn-submit').click()
sleep(3)
```

But when I mannually try to log site show no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question and the *url* `https://reg.usps.com/login?app=MyUSPS` to login using *username* and *password* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired elements to be *clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://reg.usps.com/login?app=MyUSPS")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control' and @id='username']"))).send_keys("Ankit")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='form-control' and @id='password']").send_keys("Ankit")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block' and @id='btn-submit']").click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: usps_com]

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB i have another question.

Comment: My code worked for firefox but not for chrome.Do you know why?

Comment: @Ankit I am not sure why it didn't work with _Chrome_ at your end but at my end it worked perfecto with the combo of _Selenium v3.14_, _ChromeDriver v2.41_ and _Chrome v68.0_. Are you using the updated binaries?